# Return a cell value if the criteria is met

Tags: arrays, indexing, excel-formula, match, countif

This might be a simple question for most of you but your help will be appreciated.

I'm trying to return a cell value from 'Site Name' column, if 'Second ID' column is same as previous row and 'Primary ID' column has a '5800' in it. Expected outcome is in 'Return Value' column.

I tried CountIFs but some other formulas but got stuck.

TIA for helping.

Example:
[image]

Comment: It's better to post data as data, than as an image. You could manage that with help of this tool: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Answer (score 0):

You could use `=XLOOKUP(1,($B$2:$B$14=B2)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("5800",$C$2:$C$14))),$A$2:$A$14,"",0)`

Or in older Excel versions:
`=INDEX($A$2:$A$14,MATCH(1,($B$2:$B$14=B2)*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(5800,$C$2:$C$14))),0))`

(Enter this array formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`).

Both formulas use the same logic:
they search the 2nd ID column to find matching ID's and search the primary ID column for ID's containing text `5800` (the `"` could be omitted, since 5800 is a number. I think in your case `LEFT (range,4)="5800"` could also be used).

If found it returns the first matching site name.

Note that this formula doesn't check for

> if 'Second ID' column is same as previous row`

It checks for matching Second ID regardless it's position.

I figured that's what you ment. If not, let me know.

Comment: Thank you P.b. for sharing formula and apologies I couldn't respond in time. It works perfectly.

Comment: There's no time restraint in responding. Glad I could help. If this answer your question, please mark my answer as correct by clicking the green checkmark to the left of my post.